# Mean and Standard Deviation accuracy

Tags: math, image-processing, vb6

I'm using VB 6.0 to calculate the mean and standard deviation of the red channel of image. The functions is correct but they are not correct in companion with other applications. This is the code I wrote :
For example, the mean in my code = 240 while other applications it 238 the difference is little but how I can make it accurate ?

```
Sub TORGB(ByVal Col As Long, R As Double, G As Double, B As Double)
    R = Col And &HFF
    G = (Col \ &H100) And &HFF
    B = (Col \ &H10000) And &HFF   
End Sub 

Dim sumr As Single
Dim meanr As Single
Dim SDr As Single
sumr = 0
For y = 0 To Pic.ScaleHeight - 1
    For x = 0 To Pic.ScaleWidth - 1
                PixelValue = GetPixel(Pic.hdc, x, y)
                TORGB PixelValue, R, G, B
                sumr = sumr + R
Next x : Next y
si = Pic.ScaleWidth * Pic.ScaleHeight
meanr = sumr / si
```

Comment: You're looping on Pic but getting the pixel from PicSample?  Is this a typo or could this be your mistake?

Comment: change sumr to a double.

Comment: @GMastros it was a mistake, I corrected it and I changed to Double nothing changed

Comment: I'd guess your `si` is off a bit.  Just changing ScaleMode to pixels doesn't mean the metrics have integer pixel-precision.  You are working though OLE and everything gets converted to and from HiMetric internal values.